# Is it possible to send a struct with SSL_write and SSL_read?

Tags: c, openssl

Is it possible to send and recieve a structure with SSL_write and SSL_read?

Client

```
typedef struct{
      unsigned int userid;
      unsigned int name;        
} sendInfo;

  sendInfo infofile;



SSL_write(ssl, infofile, sizeof(struct infofile));
```

Server

```
bytes = SSL_read(ssl, struct(infofile), sizeof(struct infofile) );
```

Is there other methods to send a structure?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do this in general. C data structures do not have a mandatory, universal memory layout that's the same on all architectures and platforms. When you serialize data, you always have to break it down into individual parts (integers and byte sequences), and moreover you will have to specify the size and ordering (endianness) of all multibyte fields like integers.

Imagine that you find a block of bytes on the street. How would you know what it means? When you serialize, you have to publish a specification of the format, something which you could apply to your found bytes and say, "this is the first integer", "this is a sequence of bytes, counted by the previously read integer", etc. With this information, the corresponding deserializing code can rebuild the internal data structure.

A typical serialization field would be something like "unsigned 32-bit integer, little-endian". That means you have to write out bytes `n & 0xFF`, `(n >> 8) & 0xFF`, `(n >> 16) 0xFF`, `(n >> 24) & 0xFF`, and you read back in `buf[0] + (buf[1] << 8) + (buf[2] << 16) + (buf[3] << 24)`. Note that you'll never have to know anything about your platform, but only about the wire format.

Comment: True. And I'm out to look for blocks of bytes layout around on the streets!

Comment: I send `struct` all the time (have been for past 15 years) over a Windows socket using C++ to a microcontroller running C. Never have any issues whatsoever.

Comment: @0A0D: Those would definitely be the most awesome Famous Last Words :-)

Comment: It would except I have trusted it to run parking garages with millions of transactions across the world :)

Comment: @0A0D: If you only ever have two fixed platforms, it's possible to find out how language constructs are implemented and use this assumption. It's just not portable, non-local (the assumption isn't documented by the code itself), and the layout of structs is fraught with subtlety (like padding) which makes them brittle and dangerous when the new intern wants to add a couple of fields "because it worked so well in the past". No doubt that you can get away with it; I just wouldn't.

Comment: Yes, but if there is no padding and it is just a stream of bytes, it is entirely portable especially if you know the platform. The key is maintaining your 4 byte boundaries.

Comment: "portable if you know the platform" is a strange phrase if I've heard one! I don't think the standard guarantees the absence of padding, either... OK, anyway: First off, you'll have to find a way to guarantee the sizes of the constituent types (the OP's `unsigned int` fails that already). Something like `uint32_t` comes to mind. Then you could add a (static) assertion that the size of the struct equals the sum of the sizes of its parts. Now you still have to get the endianness right. I can see the appeal -- doesn't the new C1x add some alignment stuff to standardize this "existing practice"?

Comment: Can't speak specificially on C1x because I am not an expert on it, but I can guarantee that the `struct` is sent and received the same way on varied platforms from embedded to C++ to C# applications. You have to have an agreed upon ICD between systems to ensure the data is received and sent in the right way. Meaning, you can't have an `int` defined elsewhere in the `struct` when it should be at the beginning, for instance. Plus, as far as adding something to the struct. That's OK - but you have to ensure that your boundaries are maintained (e.g. 4 byte boundary)

Comment: and if you add something, you should plan ahead so you don't break existing systems (e.g. add an array of `char` somewhere in your `struct` as a placeholder for future "expansion"). That is the only disadvantage I see is that if you add something later, then it could break older systems and then it is not backwards compatible (which I have seen in the past). But the approach does work.

Answer (score 0):

Except for you probably meant `&infofile`.